# Remove "Pay with credit card" from express checkout in Paypal

Tags: paypal

I already accept credit cards with 2checkout in ecwid.com
I added express checkout with the API Paypal integration.

I asked them how to do it but they said that I have to fix the settings in my Paypal account, I ask Paypal support and the have told me that is not possible, but I know many people have done it.

I don't want to accept cards with Paypal since there is not much protection against chargebacks.

Can you please help me with this? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes David is right , Just login to the PayPal account and go to this url :

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments

and turn off the "account optional" settings there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about requiring a Paypal account, you can set this in `merchant account settings` under PayPal Account Optional. From what I can tell you can also pass a parameter too depending on your implementation.

Comment: `SOLUTIONTYPE` set to `Mark` https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Thanks David, but I don't understand were should I put this, I mean is there a program that I have to download, a section in my paypal account, I am new with this and the paypal documentation is too much and not user friendly  :(

Comment: It is one of the post parameters you pass to Paypal for express checkout when you transfer the customer to Paypal

Answer (score 0):

log into your paypal account at www.paypal.com
click on the settings cog
goto My selling preferences
goto Website preferences
disable PayPal account optional setting
job done